# one one function from $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$ which also satisfies metric condition.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Can we think of a one one function from ${Q\cap[0,1]}\times {Q\cap[0,1]} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ which has and additional property that it maintains distances order?

What i mean is that if we write $f(x_i,y_i) = c_i$, then

$$\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}<\sqrt{(x_3-x_4)^2+(y_3-y_4)^2} 
\Rightarrow |c_1-c_2|<|c_3-c_4|.$$

What this will help is to completely get rid of the distance function in finding the shortest part through a messy calculation and directly using the difference operation.

Comment: not sure why people are voting to close

Comment: even I dont know. This one has some really good implications in programming and I had a real life use on it. 
Either it seems to easy to solve for the people here. (which to me it does not) or it is too difficult and obviously a problem without any solution.)

But then I dont even know if I am allowed to comment here to defend the question...

Answer (score 0):

There is no one-to-one continuous function from $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb R$. While this doesn't completely answer your question, it makes it hard to belive that a function such as the one that you are interested in exists and it is computationaly useful.

Comment: ok. I have changed the question from RxR to [0,1]x[0,1] but since the cardinality of [0,1]  is same as R I dont think that is going to help much either... :(

Comment: @NishantSah It will not help at all. There is no one-to-one function from $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ into $\mathbb R$ either.

Comment: You need the word "continuous" in that last comment.

Comment: @zhw. Yes. Sure. I forgot that.

Comment: I have changed the requirement and made the domain a part of QxQ. In the hope that the cardinality is reduced by such an extent that it gives some better hope to achieve one such function..
I understand how difficult the original condition was but in usng the real world latitude longitudes, data is almost ceratinly saved as rational coordinate not a real number.

Comment: But the target space is still $\mathbb R?$